# React setState with nested Json

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, reactjs

I just started to teach myself some React. In my first project I'm trying to create some basic charts with data from an Corona Dataset. The dataset gets created by my own restapi and looks like this:

```
[{
    "Bundesland": "Bayern",
    "Landkreis": "LK Erlangen-H\u00f6chstadt",
    "Altersgruppe": "A80+",
    "Geschlecht": "W",
    "AnzahlFall": 1,
    "AnzahlTodesfall": 0,
    "Meldedatum": 1577836800000,
    "IdLandkreis": "09572",
    "Datenstand": "05.01.2021, 00:00 Uhr",
    "NeuerFall": 0,
    "NeuerTodesfall": -9,
    "NeuGenesen": 0,
    "AnzahlGenesen": 1
  },
  {
    "Bundesland": "Nordrhein-Westfalen",
    "Landkreis": "SK K\u00f6ln",
    "Altersgruppe": "A35-A59",
    "Geschlecht": "W",
    "AnzahlFall": 1,
    "AnzahlTodesfall": 0,
    "Meldedatum": 1577923200000,
    "IdLandkreis": "05315",
    "Datenstand": "05.01.2021, 00:00 Uhr",
    "NeuerFall": 0,
    "NeuerTodesfall": -9,
    "NeuGenesen": 0,
    "AnzahlGenesen": 1
  }]
```

After I fetched the data by using the useEffect-Hook, I'm trying to use the useState-Hook to declare a new data variable that I can pass different react components

My current code method looks like this:

```
const [corona, setCorona] = useState([])

useEffect(() => {
    d3.json(path).then(res => { 
        let data = res
        setCorona(data)
    }).catch(err =>{console.log(err)})
},[])
```

I assume that the api call is working, since i can log the result. However, I am not able to declare *corona* by using my current *setCorona* method

Edit: This is the response from the api call
[image: Response Api Call]

Comment: If you have verified that corona is set to the correct value then I am not sure what your actual issue is? I don't see anything obviously wrong in this code snippet.

Comment: Might be the problem that I am trying to use the whole json as value for corona?

Comment: While you might run into performance issues with rendering an overly large dataset there is nothing actually wrong with using it.  Your question doesnt really make sense though. You don't declare corona when you call setCorona.  You can mostly think of it as an assignment to corona.

Answer (score 1):

React's setState is asynchronous. Do not reflect the change immediately (like console-log just after setState). I am assuming that's the issue.

---

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';

const data = [{
    "Bundesland": "Bayern",
    "Landkreis": "LK Erlangen-H\u00f6chstadt",
    "Altersgruppe": "A80+",
    "Geschlecht": "W",
    "AnzahlFall": 1,
    "AnzahlTodesfall": 0,
    "Meldedatum": 1577836800000,
    "IdLandkreis": "09572",
    "Datenstand": "05.01.2021, 00:00 Uhr",
    "NeuerFall": 0,
    "NeuerTodesfall": -9,
    "NeuGenesen": 0,
    "AnzahlGenesen": 1
},
{
    "Bundesland": "Nordrhein-Westfalen",
    "Landkreis": "SK K\u00f6ln",
    "Altersgruppe": "A35-A59",
    "Geschlecht": "W",
    "AnzahlFall": 1,
    "AnzahlTodesfall": 0,
    "Meldedatum": 1577923200000,
    "IdLandkreis": "05315",
    "Datenstand": "05.01.2021, 00:00 Uhr",
    "NeuerFall": 0,
    "NeuerTodesfall": -9,
    "NeuGenesen": 0,
    "AnzahlGenesen": 1
}]

function Fun(props) {

    const [corona, setCorona] = useState([])

    const handleClick = () => {
        setCorona(data)
    }

    // This function logs value of corona.
    useEffect(() => {
        console.log('Logging corona to prove that it is updated.', corona);
    }, [corona]);

    return (
        <div>
            <button onClick={handleClick}> Click to update update corona. </button>
        </div>
    );
}

export default Fun;
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, helps me a lot to understand the logic behind react! Instead of using a handleClick like you did in your example code, could I create an function that calls setState for example every 30secs?

Comment: @rin_o 
Check this. https://reactgo.com/react-setinterval/

Answer (score 0):

I dont really understand what u want to do..-
Something like this?

```
const [corona, setCorona] = useState([])

useEffect(() => {
    d3.json(path).then(res => { 
        setCorona(res.data)
    }).catch(err =>{console.log(err)})
},[])

return (
  <div> {corona.map()..... and so on} </div>
OR
   <div> {corona[0].Bundesland} </div>

)
```

Comment: I'm trying to set the json as array to the corona variable, so that I can implement the values from the array within the html or pass them to a different react component. The problem is that corona is an empty array, even after calling setCorona()

Comment: @rin_o first console log 'res' after the 'then'. Take a look what did you get from the server. Then choose the right object and set it to your state corona. Then add another console log just before the return to see what value will be re-rendred in this variable. It should work.

Comment: @ZiedHf thanks for your input, helped me a lot! However, if I'm using the example above, I get the TypeError: Cannot read property 'Bundesland' of undefined. The array is still empty. But, if I focus on one specific value from the json, I can return the value within the html

Comment: @rin_o If the default value of corona is null, undefined or an empty array, then sure your app will crash. Write this instead : corona[ && corona[0] && corona[0].Bundesland